# Not able torun greeter_client helloworld sample project on QNX

Tags: grpc, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I have cross-compiled the code successfully for QNX ARM 7.0, and able to generate the binaries.

Very first thing I am going to do is to run the helloworld code on the target. So I built the helloworld code available in cpp folder(since I am using cpp). I copied only two files greeter_server and greeter_client in target machine.
I am able to start server using greeter_server successfully.
But when I run greeter_client in another window, I get failure message.

```
14: DNS resolution failed
Greeter received: RPC failed
```

[Here is the logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_kv0PxlcvzHlffVxdQn-KkBBmALQ3x2P/view?usp=sharing) after enabling GRPC_TRACE=ALL, GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG.

Please help me know the issue.

We do not have DNS server, I tried using GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER=native, but did not helped.
Let me know if anyone knows to configure the DNS in QNX.

Comment: This is mostly a guess. I'm unfamiliar with QNX and C++.... But... curiously you have logs where resolution appears to succeed `host:localhost port:33731` but the gRPC server is described as `name:localhost:50051, default_port=https`. Is it an issue parsing the name? It should be `localhost` and not `https` (==443) but `50051`

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin for your reply. But if I compare this logs with linux logs, both have same logs. I mean in linux also it is showing name:localhost:50051, default_port=https.
Do we need the DNS server? if not then what is missing from my side?

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm unfamiliar with QNX and C++ so can't be much help. Did you try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`? I would expect `localhost` to possibly require DNS whereas the IP address should not.

Comment: Check that you have valid nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf. gRPC-C++ uses C-Ares lib by default which looks for nameserver address in this file.

Comment: Thanks DazWilkin, it resolved the issue, by replacing 127.0.0.1